# How to get total time from a start and finish time using django TimeField?

Tags: python, django

So lets say I have to TimeField's in my model. One for start and one for finish. How would I get a total time from that? Basically I have this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
date = models.DateField()
time_started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
time_finished = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I want to do something like a model method or a view function maybe like this:

```
 def get_total_time(self):
        return time_finished - time_started
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: Likely the `time_started` and/or `time_finised` is `None` (`NULL`), hence then you can not calculate the time difference.

Comment: could you post the traceback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a property that calculates the duration, so the difference between `time_finished` and `time_started`. However, you should check if both are not `None`. If one (or both) are `None`, you can for example return `None`:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateField()
    time_started = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    time_finished = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def duration(self):
        if self.time_finished is not None and self.time_started is not None:
            return self.time_finished - self.time_started

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```